# Tree structure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2008;

I have a tree. I need to get all child nodes of node n (see diagram) and all child nodes of these child nodes, etc until the leaf nodes which is fairly trivial. I also need to be able to say 'Take node o, go up the tree until we reach m and because m is a child of node n set some property of node o to some property of node m. Node o could be 3 levels deep (as illustrated) or 45 levels deep, x levels deep.

This gets all children of a given node (or area)

```
    --Return all sub-area structure of an area:

      WITH temp_areas (ParentAreaID, AreaID, [Name], [Level]) AS
      (
            SELECT ParentAreaID, AreaID, [Name], 0
            FROM lib_areas WHERE AreaID = @AreaID
            UNION ALL
            SELECT B.ParentAreaID, B.AreaID, B.[Name], A.Level + 1
            FROM temp_areas AS A, lib_areas AS B
            WHERE A.AreaID = B.ParentAreaID
      )

INSERT INTO @files (id) SELECT fileid FROM lib_filesareasxref where areaid in (select  areaid from temp_areas)

while exists (select * from @files)
begin
select top 1
@ID = id
from
@files ORDER BY id DESC

delete from @files where id = @id
```

[image: tree]

Comment: Is your question "Does this make sense?" or is there more to it than that?

Comment: Please show the results you expect for your example.  Such as, do you need to know the depth of each node?  Or the depth relative to `m`, or the depth relative to `o`?  If you define your output we can demonstrate the code.

Comment: Okay, I will show sample results. I don't need to know the depth of each node, no.

Comment: Is this SQL Server or something else?

Comment: @podiluska, no that's not my question. Sorry for not being clear, I was just making sure that my explanation of the problem was clear as I had doubts if it was or not. My question is how to implement the behavior I described (with nodes n,m and o).

Comment: This is SQL Server, yes.

Comment: You say that **O** should get something from **M**. So from **O** go up until you find **M**, then set something on **O** from **M**. What significance does **N** have in that case?

Comment: N sets the position of M in the tree. M is always a child of N.

Comment: So if finding **M** requires going above **N**, then no update?

Comment: Correct. Once N is reached we don't go any higher. M will never be above N, if it is then there is no N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will track back from `@node_o` until it reaches `@node_m` or it reaches the top of the tree *(if `@node_m` is not above `@node_o`)*.

```
  WITH
    parents
  AS
  (
    SELECT
      A.ParentAreaID, A.AreaID, A.[Name], 0
    FROM
      lib_areas  AS A
    WHERE
      A.AreaID = @node_o

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      A.ParentAreaID, A.AreaID, A.[Name], B.Level + 1
    FROM
      lib_areas  AS A
    INNER JOIN
      parents    AS B
        ON A.AreaID = B.ParentAreaID
    WHERE
      B.AreaID <> @node_m
  )
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    parents
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose using a `HierarchyID` data type in your table, and using the `GetAncestor` method

Comment: This looks really nice but I it's not feasible to create a new table or modify the existing one in this instance.

Comment: Shame! In that case, @Dems common table expression is probably the way to go